# Move TEXT_ELEMENT using arcpy.mapping and data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I'm customizing an automated mapping solution using arcpy.mapping and data driven pages.
Using a looping statement, I'm hardcoding the position for the mapping elements (legend, north arrow, inset map, etc. so that for each map, the mapping elements do not interfere with the area of interest.  My code works for all mapping elements except for TEXT_ELEMENTS. Text element stays in the first position assigned for all of the maps.

Not quite sure why this is the case, cause I have been able to get the north arrow, a neat line, legend, scale bar, and inset map (dataframe) to move position for 16 different maps.

Sample code below showing how I'm moving the inset map and one of the text elements is shown below:

```
import arcpy, os
# Create an output directory variable
outDir = r"C:\Desktop\Test"  

# Create a new, empty pdf document in the specified output directory
finalpdf_filename = outDir + r"\FinalMapBook.pdf"
if os.path.exists(finalpdf_filename): # Check to see if file already exists, delete if it does
  os.remove(finalpdf_filename)
finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalpdf_filename)
# Create a Data Driven Pages object from the mxd 
mxdPath = r"C:\Desktop\Test\States.mxd"
tempMap = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
tempDDP = tempMap.dataDrivenPages
# Create objects for the layout elements that will be moving, e.g., inset data frame, scale text
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap, "LocatorDF")[0]  

for pgIndex in range(1, tempDDP.pageCount + 1, 1):

  # Create a name for the pdf file you will create for each page
  tempMap.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pgIndex
  pageName = tempMap.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Name
  temp_filename = r"C:\Desktop\Test\temp_pdfs\Land_Cover_" + \
                            str(pgIndex) + pageName + ".pdf"
  if os.path.exists(temp_filename):
    os.remove(temp_filename)

  #Code to modify mapping elements for each page

  # Code for Map1
  if (pgIndex == 1):

    #Set inset map position
    inset = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap, "LocatorDF")[0]
    inset.ElementPositionX = 3.25
    inset.ElementPositionY = 0
    # Move text elements
    elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(tempMap, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Westport")[0]
    elm.ElementPositionX = 0.3125   
    elm.ElementPositionY = 3.0227

  # Code for Map2
  if (pgIndex == 2):

    #Set inset map position
    inset = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap, "LocatorDF")[0]
    inset.ElementPositionX = 0
    inset.ElementPositionY = 3.25
    # Move text elements
    elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(tempMap, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Westport")[0]
    elm.ElementPositionX = 2.3125   
    elm.ElementPositionY = 2.0227


  # Code for Map3
  if (pgIndex == 3):
    #Set inset map position
    inset = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap, "LocatorDF")[0]
    inset.ElementPositionX = 3.25
    inset.ElementPositionY = 3.25
    # Move text elements
    elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(tempMap, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Westport")[0]
    elm.ElementPositionX = 1.3125   
    elm.ElementPositionY = 2.0227

  # Code to export current page and add it to mapbook
  tempDDP.exportToPDF(temp_filename, "RANGE", pgIndex)
  finalPdf.appendPages(temp_filename)

  arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

# Clean up
del tempMap

# Update the properties of the final pdf
finalPdf.updateDocProperties(pdf_open_view="USE_THUMBS",
                             pdf_layout="SINGLE_PAGE")

# Save your result
finalPdf.saveAndClose()
```

Comment: Note, if you have the (costly) ArcGIS Production Mapping extension at your disposal, you can set up Layout Rules without the need for scripting.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367344/move-text-box-automatically-when-using-data-driven-pages/367406#367406

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay a small change to the script, and to the text element properties was all I needed.
Lower case "e" for elementPositionX and Y, and under the "size and position" tab in the text element properties I gave it an "element name" for the script to search (in this case "Westport").

Now it works!

```
    # Code for Map3
  if (pgIndex == 3):
    #Set inset map position
    inset = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(tempMap, "LocatorDF")[0]
    inset.elementPositionX = 3.25
    inset.elementPositionY = 3.25
    # Move text elements
    elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(tempMap, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Westport")[0]
    elm.elementPositionX = 1.3125   
    elm.elementPositionY = 2.0227
```